# Beamer vs. Minted: overlays

Tags: beamer, overlays, minted

How to use beamer overlay inside minted code? The obvious solution does not work:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\frametitle{Foo}

\begin{minted}{lua}
\uncover<1>{print("foo")}
\uncover<2>{print("bar")}
\uncover<3>{print("baz")}
\end{minted}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no obvious way to make this work due to the way minted works internally. In fact, it is vital that the code is *not* parsed by TeX in the usual way.

There might be some trickery possible to circumvent this but for now I suggest that the easiest way to approximate the desired behaviour is to use multiple sequential `minted` environments:

```latex
\uncover<1>{\begin{minted}{lua}
print("foo")
\end{minted}}
\uncover<2>{\begin{minted}{lua}
print("bar")
\end{minted}}
\uncover<3>{\begin{minted}{lua}
print("baz")
\end{minted}}
```

Though to be honest I’m not certain if this even works.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `\uncover<x>{\begin{minted}...\end{minted}}`?

Comment: @Aaron Damn, of course. Which makes the whole thing much more difficult. I *hope* the above works at all.

Comment: It does not work for me.

Answer (score 12):

After some trial and error the following is the only solution that works for me:

```tex
\begin{frame}

\begin{overprint}
\onslide<1>
\begin{minted}{c++}
   ...
\end{minted}

\onslide<2>
\begin{minted}{c++}
   ...
\end{minted}
\end{overprint}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: What does `overprint` do?

Answer (score 12):

It seems that there's been some progress and this now works as expected:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\frametitle{Foo}

\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{lua}
|\pause|print("foo")
|\pause|print("bar")
|\pause|print("baz")
\end{minted}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

I can add that @VZ.'s solution also works if you want to "single-step" some code (in my case, C code with pointers) together with illustrations using `tikzpicture`. The "obvious" solution did not work, neither did using `escapeinside` due to a bug in `pygments` (see https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/70). In the solution below, `highlightlines` is used to highlight the current instruction. Too bad the actual C code need to be duplicate - but hey, it works!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Foo}
\begin{overprint}
\onslide<1>
\begin{minted}[linenos,highlightlines={3}]{c}
  int main(void) {
    char *p;
    p=(char *)malloc(5);
    /* do stuff */
    p=(char *)malloc(7);
    free(p);
    return 0;
  }
\end{minted}
\onslide<2>
\begin{minted}[linenos,highlightlines={5}]{c}
  int main(void) {
    char *p;
    p=(char *)malloc(5);
    /* do stuff */
    p=(char *)malloc(7);
    free(p);
    return 0;
  }
\end{minted}
\end{overprint}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node<1->[rectangle,draw] (p) {p};
  \node<1->[rectangle,draw,right of=p] (q1) {q1};
  \draw<1>[->] (p) -- (q1);
  \uncover<2->{\node[rectangle,draw,below right of=p] (q2) {q2};};
  \draw<2->[->] (p) -- (q2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot put a minted environment inside `\only` or `\uncover`, but you can use it inside minted *environments*. As usual, you still need the `fragile` option for frame. Here's an example (where `code` is a minted environment).

```
\newminted[code]{scala}{}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{code}
snippet1
\end{code}
\begin{onlyenv}<2>
\begin{code}
snippet2
\end{code}
\end{onlyenv}
\note[item]{M}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I needed and, since I'm a beamer noob, I didn't know about `onlyenv`s

Answer (score 2):

I used something similar to what Konrad Rudolph suggested, I used `\onslide<n>` before the minted block (actually #+begin_src in emacs' orgmode). It does not require curly brackets around the block.

Answer (score -2):

The following worked for me: (I'm using Pygments 1.5 which is pre-release at the moment.)

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{...}

  \begin{minted}{haskell}
    data C a = ...
  \end{minted}

  \begin{minted}{c++}
    template<typename T> class C {...};
  \end{minted}

  \begin{minted}{scala}
    class C[T] {...};
  \end{minted}
\end{frame}
```

The **`fragile`** keyword is in fact what does the trick for me. (Note its use after `\begin{frame}`.)

Comment: Don't see any overlays in your code.