# Can you use beamer + minted + tikz to single-step code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays, minted

I have some C pointer code that I would like to "single-step" to show what happens with e.g. dangling pointers. I use `minted` for syntax highlighting, and that seems to be causing the problem.

The code below compiles (with `-shell-escape`), but the code that should be escaped isn't. The reason seem to be a bug in `pygments` (see https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/70). I have also tried to solution of `marvin2k` that re-defined `!`, but failed to get that code to work.I have also tried various combinations of `\begin{minted}[highlightlines=\only<1>{3}\only<2>{5}]{c}` to no avail.

Does anyone have a solution? Edit: My platform is ubuntu 14.04, pygmentize 1.6, minted 2.4.1.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Pointers}
\begin{minted}[linenos,escapeinside=||]{c}
  int main(void) {
    char *p;
    p=(char *)malloc(5); |\only<1>{$\Leftarrow$}|
    /* do stuff */
    p=(char *)malloc(7); |\only<2>{$\Leftarrow$}|
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node<1->[rectangle,draw] (p) {p};
  \node<1->[rectangle,draw,right of=p] (q1) {q1};
  \draw<1>[->] (p) -- (q1);
  \uncover<2->{\node[rectangle,draw,below right of=p] (q2) {q2};};
  \draw<2->[->] (p) -- (q2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: First slide showing non-escape LaTeX code]

Comment: Completely unrelated but you shouldn’t cast the return value of `malloc` in C, it’s unnecessary and error-prone (since you could accidentally cast to the wrong pointer type and invoke inadvertent undefined behaviour): http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/1968

Comment: @KonradRudolph, unrelated...and you are right. It was a long time since I last did C and I haven't kept track of 'best practices'. I tried to modify my question but I don't know how to modify the image.

Answer (score 8):

As `<` and `>` are problematic with `minted`, you may define the `\myonly` command:

```
\newcommand\myonly[2]{\only<#1>{#2}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted,tikz}
\newcommand\myonly[2]{\only<#1>{#2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Pointers}
\begin{minted}[linenos,escapeinside=||]{c}
  int main(void) {
    char *p;
    p=(char *)malloc(5); |\myonly{1}{$\Leftarrow$}|
    /* do stuff */
    p=(char *)malloc(7); |\myonly{2}{$\Leftarrow$}|
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node<1->[rectangle,draw] (p) {p};
  \node<1->[rectangle,draw,right of=p] (q1) {q1};
  \draw<1>[->] (p) -- (q1);
  \uncover<2->{\node[rectangle,draw,below right of=p] (q2) {q2};};
  \draw<2->[->] (p) -- (q2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's odd...when I compile your solution (ubuntu 14.04, pygmentize v1.6, minted v2.4.1), my problem remains. What setup did you use?

Comment: @NiclasBörlin I use TeXLive 2016, pygmentize 2.1.3 and minted 2.4.1.

Comment: It looks like I need to upgrade pygmentize then... Do you run Linux or something else?

Comment: @NiclasBörlin I use Ubuntu 16.10.

Answer (score 5):

The best solution I have so far is based on @VZ.'s `overprint` solution (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51618/35602). However, it would be nice with a solution that did not require the C code to be repeated...

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Foo}
\begin{overprint}
\onslide<1>
\begin{minted}[linenos,highlightlines={3}]{c}
  int main(void) {
    char *p;
    p=(char *)malloc(5);
    /* do stuff */
    p=(char *)malloc(7);
    free(p);
    return 0;
  }
\end{minted}
\onslide<2>
\begin{minted}[linenos,highlightlines={5}]{c}
  int main(void) {
    char *p;
    p=(char *)malloc(5);
    /* do stuff */
    p=(char *)malloc(7);
    free(p);
    return 0;
  }
\end{minted}
\end{overprint}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node<1->[rectangle,draw] (p) {p};
  \node<1->[rectangle,draw,right of=p] (q1) {q1};
  \draw<1>[->] (p) -- (q1);
  \uncover<2->{\node[rectangle,draw,below right of=p] (q2) {q2};};
  \draw<2->[->] (p) -- (q2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```