# How do I "disable" code lines in minted (in beamer)?

Tags: beamer, minted

I want to reproduce the following screenshot with minted (in beamer, though I don't think that matters).
How would I go about doing that?[image: code image]

Comment: Please show us what you try so far!

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the same technique as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/581865/36296 with transparent overlays:

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\frametitle{Foo}

\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{lua}
print("foo")
|\pause|print("bar")
|\pause|print("baz")
\end{minted}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]